# JMeter and Selenium Integration

Tags: selenium, jmeter, automation-testing

I have written Selenium Automation Test Scripts using Page Object Model. The scripts work well and no complaints there.
I want to now do performance testing of the application and am planning to use Jmeter for the same.

Is there a way I can use the selenium scripts & jmeter together to do the performance testing.

My aim is to write the scripts only once (in Selenium) and reuse them for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is Webdriver plugin for JMeter

https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver

Alternatively you can download the same from plugins manager as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use Selenium for performance testing because it's generally not [recommended](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/) as it doesn't make a lot of sense.

If you need details:

1. You won't have metrics and KPIs which JMeter normally gives you if you're using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Browsers are **very** resource intensive, an instance of browser requires a [CPU core and 2 GB of RAM](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/99.0/system-requirements/) (if not more) so with 8x CPU cores and 16 GB of RAM you will be able to kick off only 7 browser instances and if you will be using JMeter it will be thousands of virtual users because Java thread has much less resource footprint

Wouldn't it be better to [convert your Selenium tests into "pure" JMeter](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/99.0/system-requirements/) instead?